# Set the scroll at the end of ViewGroup when new item is added

Tags: android

According to this [example](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/layout.html) is posible add new items programmatically to a ViewGroup, but I can't find the way to set the scroll at the end of the list.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it a `ScrollView`? Then you can use [`scrollTo()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html#scrollTo%28int,%20int%29) or [`smoothScrollTo()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html#smoothScrollTo%28int,%20int%29).

`ListView`, by the way, has [`smoothScrollToPosition()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#smoothScrollToPosition%28int%29).

Comment: No, is just a ViewGroup.

Comment: @Ricardo Then you will need a `ScrollView` somewhere in the view hierarchy. Normal ViewGroups do not scroll by themselves.